# General Number Field Sieve Implementation.

Tags: number-theory, optimization, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, python

Recently I have found interest in prime factorizations and through another post found out that Number Field Sieve was the best algorithm for factoring large numbers. I tried doing some research but couldn't find any python implementations of it and decided I want to try making it myself. Can anyone direct me to a resource that really explains all the inner workings of it so that I can have enough knowledge to try to implement this in python? Thanks.